My 9 month old kitten has a small injury on her back and a bit of a limp
So today Pip came inside today after being out in the garden, and clearly had a bit of a limp and was struggling to jump. I found a matted part of her fur and underneath it there is definitely some sort of injury there, i've attached a picture of it. Basically I'm trying to evaluate the situation, looking for any advice to take care of her, or whether its time to go to a vet?
Thanks for any advice


If in doubt, vet.

Fair, can't argue with that
